# не разворачивается веб страница на nginx при запуске контейнера. При переходе на 0.0.0.0:80 показывается страница: Welcome to nginx

Tags: linux, ubuntu, nginx, docker, devops

мой dockerfile:

```
FROM node:alpine as builder

WORKDIR /app

COPY package.json package-lock.json ./
ENV CI=1
COPY . .
RUN yarn


#RUN npm run-script build --prod -output-path=/_site
RUN npm run-script build


FROM nginx:alpine
RUN rm -rf /usr/share/nginx/html/*
COPY --from=builder ./app/_site /usr/share/nginx/html


COPY ./nginx.conf /etc/nginx/nginx.conf
EXPOSE 80
ENTRYPOINT ["nginx", "-g", "daemon off;"]
```

nginx.conf:

```
    user dmitry;

    worker_processes  1;

    events {

     worker_connections  80;

    }

    http {

     include /etc/nginx/mime.types;

     default_type application/octet-stream;

     server {

      listen 80;

      server_name localhost;

     }

    }
```

Comment: Ну раз вы скопировали папку `_site`, то видимо если открыть `0.0.0.0:80/_site/` то там что-нибудь будет

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В комментарии верно по существу, но не предложено решение.

Исправьте команду копирования на

```
COPY --from=builder ./app/_site/ /usr/share/nginx/html
```

Копируем каталог или копируем его содержимое - две большие разницы :)